# How to transform Array to Object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, reduce

What is the best way to transform an array like this:

```
const arr = [
  { name: 'Bob' },
  { name: 'Ben' }
  { name: 'Cole' }
  { name: 'Mary' }
  { name: 'Travis' }
]
```

to an object like:

```
const obj = {
  'B': ['Bob', 'Ben'],
  'C': ['Cole'],
  'M': ['Mary'],
  'T': ['Travis']
}
```

Using only vanilla JS

Comment: You tagged the queston [reduce], so you should already know...

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Unfortunately, I don't fully understand how to make it using reduce. I just know that if I need to transform array to object, there's a method in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an array where the key is the first letter of the name using the reduce function and restructuring the 'name' from the objects. If the key exists in the array the name is pushed (using spread operator). Else, it creates the key with only one element.

```
const arr = [
  { name: 'Bob' },
  { name: 'Ben' },
  { name: 'Cole' },
  { name: 'Mary' },
  { name: 'Travis' }
];

const obj = arr.reduce((res, {name})=>{
  res[name[0]] = res[name[0]] ? [...res[name[0]],name] : [name];
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Code only answers are not ideal, would you mind adding a description?

Comment: I created an array where the key is the first letter of the name using the reduce function and destructruing the 'name' from the objects. If the key exists in the array the name is pushed (using spread operator). Else, it creates the key with only one element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array#reduce`. Iterate through each object of your array and then extract out the first letter and add names corresponding to it.

```js
const arr = [{name: 'Bob'}, {name: 'Ben'}, {name: 'Cole'}, {name: 'Mary'}, {name: 'Travis'}],
      result = arr.reduce((r,{name}) => {
        r[name[0]] = r[name[0]] || [];
        r[name[0]].push(name);
        return r;
      },{});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla JS you say? Here you go

```js
let nil      = x => x === undefined;
let empty    = ([h]) => nil(h);
let first    = ([h]) => h;
let last     = ([h, ...t]) => empty(t) ? h : last(t);
let map      = ([h, ...t], f) => nil(h) ? [] : [f(h), ...map(t, f)];
let reduce   = ([h, ...t], f, i) => nil(h) ? i : reduce(t, f, f(i, h));
let tab      = (a, f) => map(a, x => [x, f(x)]);
let push     = (a, x) => nil(a) ? [x] : [...a, x];
let groupBy  = (a, f) => _groupBy(tab(a, f));
let _groupBy = ka => reduce(ka, (g, [x, k]) => ({...g, [k]: push(g[k], x)}), {});

///

const arr = [{ name: 'Bob' },{ name: 'Ben' },{ name: 'Cole' },{ name: 'Mary' },{ name: 'Travis' }]
z = groupBy(map(arr, x => x.name), first)
console.log(z)
```

No built-ins!

Comment: Are you trying to kill this poor guy? That's a little bit too awesome!

Comment: Just wondering why map and reduce methods are not considered as  Vanilla JS?

Comment: @nutboltu: since the OP asked for a vanilla solution, they're obviously more interested in how things work rather than getting the job done.

Comment: @georg I'm not sure that i've meant what you've said above. I was interested how to solve my problem without using libs :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let obj = {};
arr.forEach( e => {
  const name = e.name;
  if (!obj[name.charAt(0)]) obj[name.charAt(0)] = [];
  obj[name.charAt(0)].push(name);
})
```

I'm generating a new object and adding to it news keys based in the first char of the name values (only if the key hasn't been already added).
Then, I add each value to the key that corresponds.

Answer (score 0):

I think this thread is missing a *non functional* answer, so here it is:

```
const obj = {};

for(const {name} of arr)
  (obj[name[0]] || (obj[name[0]] = [])).push({name});
```